# How to open thread using process?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I have a thread to write in file using some PrintWriter

```
class NThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    PrintWriter w;

    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public NThread(int p, PrintWriter w) {
        t = new Thread(this);
        this.w = w;
        t.setPriority(p);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            w.println("Id: " + t.getId());
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }
}
```

and I try to using new process open this thread.

```
public class FileWrite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        Thread ref_mainThread=Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("C:\\write.txt");
            printWriter.println("Id main thread" + ref_mainThread);
            NThread p1=new NThread(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 4,printWriter);
            Process process1 = new ProcessBuilder("p1",".start()").start();
            try  {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            process1.destroy();
            printWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I try to write in one file by two processes. How I can do it?

Comment: Before write program you must read java-doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Process process1 = new ProcessBuilder("p1",".start()").start();

You are telling the operating system to run a program named "p1", with ".start()" as its first command line argument.

If you're on Linux, it's the same as if you typed "p1 .start" in a shell window.  If you're on Windows, its the same as if you typed that in a CMD.EXE window.  Either way, it's not going to do what you think it's going to do.

The `p1` in  `NThread p1=new NThread(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 4,printWriter);` is a variable in your Java program.  The fact that it refers to an object that can be used to start a thread will not cause a program named p1 to magically appear on your $PATH (or %PATH% if you're on Windows.)

Comment: @user3660090, You haven't said what the problem is. Why do you want two processes?  If you were hoping to do something like the Unix fork() system call in Java you are out of luck.  There is no Java equivalent to that.  The Java ProcessBuilder class can be used to start another process, but it is limited to starting processes that you could have started from a Unix shell or Windows CMD prompt.  If you write a separate program that can be started from a shell/CMD prompt, then you can start that from your Java program using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: I need to write in one file by the two processes simultaneously. First, I wrote a class thread  for write to one file in one time by two threads simultaneously , but now I need to open this threads on the process to show this threads on windows task manager. What is way to write in one file by the two processes simultaneously on java?